# Why newly created app in react have low site performance in lighthouse

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, create-react-app, lighthouse

Want to get reasons why the newly created app has a low score in the lighthouse.
Currently showing a score of 28.
Please help me to get a possible solution to increase the site performance
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the issues mentioned in the lighthouse one by one.

React and Virtual DOM suffer from slow performance. Use a faster JS framework like Solid-js.
https://solidjs.com/

Watch this video for general performance issues:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lh9q3h2khlc

Use this website to know the cost of your dependencies:
https://bundlephobia.com/package/react-dom@17.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Note that there's a big difference if you run these tests on `dev` mode or `production` mode.

I assume that if you'll build it in production mode and deploy it to `netlify` or another hosting provider, you'll see different numbers.